# Pegar content de projeto no MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, xna, contents, monogame

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem PNG no meu jogo, mas não estou conseguindo, a imagem está em `Content/alien.png`, com o código abaixo:

```
Texture2D alien;
.
.
.
protected override void LoadContent ()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch (GraphicsDevice);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    alien = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"alien");
}
```

Quando executo o jogo, aparece a mensagem de erro:

> **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: Could not load
>   alien asset as a non-content file!** --->
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The directory
>   was not found. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a part of the path
>   "/home/leonardo/Documentos/Mono/MaisUM/MaisUM/bin/Debug/Content/alien.xnb".
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001cf] in
>   :0   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
>   access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.TitleContainer.OpenStream (System.String name)
>   [0x00029] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.OpenStream
>   (System.String assetName) [0x0002e] in
>   :0   --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.OpenStream
>   (System.String assetName) [0x00053] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T]
>   (System.String assetName, System.Action`1[T] recordDisposableObject)
>   [0x00073] in <c33f6c525d914593acc9b590397e7c2b>:0   --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T]
>   (System.String assetName, System.Action`1[T] recordDisposableObject)
>   [0x0012b] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T] (System.String
>   assetName) [0x00068] in :0   at
>   MaisUM.Game1.LoadContent () [0x0002e] in
>   /home/leonardo/Documentos/Mono/MaisUM/MaisUM/Game1.cs:46   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize () [0x0004d] in
>   :0   at MaisUM.Game1.Initialize ()
>   [0x00002] in /home/leonardo/Documentos/Mono/MaisUM/MaisUM/Game1.cs:35 
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize () [0x00011] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run
>   (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameRunBehavior runBehavior) [0x00033] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run () [0x0000c] in
>   :0   at MaisUM.Program.RunGame ()
>   [0x00010] in
>   /home/leonardo/Documentos/Mono/MaisUM/MaisUM/Program.cs:31   at
>   MaisUM.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in
>   /home/leonardo/Documentos/Mono/MaisUM/MaisUM/Program.cs:55

Provavelmente e erro é porque ele espera um arquivo .xnb, mas tenho apenas um .png, pois no Linux não achei um meio de converter. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Informações:
Linux Elementary OS Freya
MonoDevelop 5.10
MonoGame 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, descobri que tinha de abrir o *Pipeline Content*, simplesmente abrindo o arquivo `Content.mgcb`, adicionando meus contents a ele e clicando em `Build`, mas tive problemas no build, estava dando falha, então eu instalei o *MonoGame 3.4* por cima do *3.5*, após isso apaguei o *3.4*, e instalei o *3.5* novamente, aí funcionou. Pode ser alguns arquivos que não tenham sido extraídos durante a primeira instalação.

Answer (score 0):

Isso realmente causa muita confusão, pois no XNA era apenas necessário que criar uma pasta e colocar os arquivos dentro(apenas com os arquivo de áudio era necessário a utilização do XACT) já no Monogame todos os arquivos devem ser adicionados/convertidos através do "Monogame Pipeline". 
IPC.: Não esqueça de fazer as devidas configurações nas propriedades do arquivo (building, copy always, etc) pois isso tb atrapalha muito na hora de adicionar os arquivos.